# isAdmin disappearing from Firebase RealTime Database when logging with Admin Account

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

i am trying to set admin routes using Angular and Firebase real time database so that users with admin privileges can access certain parts of the website. I have set isAdmin: true for the admin account. However, upon logging in with the admin account, the isAdmin turns red and gets deleted automatically.

## app-user.ts

```
export interface AppUser{
    name: string;
    isAdmin: boolean;
    email: string;
    
}
```

## user.service.ts

```
constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  save(user: firebase.User){
    this.db.object('/users/' + user.uid).set({
      name: user.displayName,
      email: user.email
    });
  }

  get(uid: string): Observable<any>{
    return this.db.object('/users/'+uid).valueChanges();
  }
```

## auth.service.ts

```
export class AuthService {
  user$: Observable<firebase.User>;

  constructor(private afAuth: AngularFireAuth, private route: ActivatedRoute, private userService: UserService) {
    this.user$=afAuth.authState;
   }

  login(){
    let returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('returnUrl') || '/';
    localStorage.setItem('returnUrl', returnUrl);

    this.afAuth.auth.signInWithRedirect(new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider);
  }

  logout(){
    this.afAuth.auth.signOut();
  }

  get appUser$(): Observable<AppUser> {
    return this.user$.pipe(
      switchMap((user) => {
        if (user) {
          return this.userService.get(user.uid);
        } else {
          return of(null);
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

## auth-guard.service.ts

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private router: Router) { }

  canActivate() {
      return this.auth.user$.pipe(map(user => {
      if(user) return true;
      
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }));

  }
}
```

## admin-auth-guard.service.ts

```
export class AdminAuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
  
  constructor(private auth: AuthService, private userService: UserService) { }

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.auth.user$.pipe(switchMap((user: firebase.User) =>
        this.userService.get(user.uid)),
        map((appUser) => appUser.isAdmin));
      }
    
      
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

After hours of editing the code, i finally found the solution. So far while saving the user in the realtime database, i have been using the set method to store the user details which made the isAdmin disappear everytime when the admin logs in.

## user.service.ts

```
export class UserService {

  constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase) { }

  save(user: firebase.User){
    this.db.object('/users/' + user.uid).update({
      name: user.displayName,
      email: user.email
      
    });
  }

  get(uid: string): Observable<any>{
    return this.db.object('/users/'+uid).valueChanges();
  }
}
```